# Any way to access personal NAS from outside local network?

Tags: networking, nas, cloud

I have a Seagate Personal Cloud hooked up to my home network. I would prefer to NOT use the SDrive software to access files from outside of my local network because that software seems to mess with my automatic refresh in windows explorer.

For example, while I'm logged into the SDrive software, creating folders or files in windows explorer will not automatically pop up. I have to refresh the folder I'm working in, find the newly created folder, then rename it to my desired text. Creating a new shortcut to my desktop requires me to refresh my desktop for the icon to appear.

I know my home Public IP address and I have tried to connect remotely to the IP and port associated with my device with no luck. Any suggestions? I do NOT have a static IP, though in the last 6 years my public IP has never changed.

Comment: Do you have a static IP from your ISP?

Comment: Please click [edit] and amend your question to specify whether or not you have ordered a fixe private IP from your ISP.

Comment: Thank you. The question has been edited. I do NOT have a static IP address.

Comment: I would suggest setting up pfsense or opensense. Run through a tutorial for setting up openVPN with certificates. Finally go to noip.com and setup a free dynamic DNS account, link the dynamic DNS account in pfsense/opensense under services. Done!